# how to stop all unnecessary services in ubuntu server 20.03 LTS for lamp server?

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, php

I have linode 1 gb ram and 1 cpu the bare minimum server. I want to know what are the best steps to run lamp server on ubuntu 20.03 LTS.
I want to run

- Apache2
- mysql 8
- php 7.4

but on my server there are two service start automatically and utilize the whole system resources

1. kswapd0 take the whole cpu
2. tsm also start
3. mysql run so many threads even i set the max connection to 2

If there any OS that is made for lamp please tell me or any package that I can install that will take care of this and give me the whole power of server

Comment: If `kswapd0` is using all of your CPU, that generally means that you don't have any swap space on your system. Consider creating a swap file that is at least 4GB in size so that the OS can "breathe".  As for "best steps", this is really task-dependent. A WordPress site will not run well on this sort of server. A data collection API that receives data from IoT devices, however, will have no issues. Without knowing more about how you plan on using the system, it will be impossible to offer more specific suggestions beyond "use a swap file" ...

Comment: linode automatically create a swap space already